Replace html elements via SQL REGEX based on containing strings
E.g. From the following HTML/XML code present in my Postgres table:
<element1> test1 </element1>
<element1> test2 </element1>
<element1> test3 </element1>

I need an SQL UPDATE in order to have the following outcome:
<element1> test1 </element1>
  test2 
<element1> test3 </element1>

I already tried the following SQL UPDATE
UPDATE table_name

SET field_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(
    field_name,
    '<element1[^>]*>.*?test2.*?</element1>',
    'test2',
    'g'
)

WHERE field_name LIKE '%test2%'

RETURNING *;

However the the outcome will be only "test2"
Do you have any idea of how to reach the following outcome?
<element1> test1 </element1>
  test2 
<element1> test3 </element1>


This question is similar to: How to use Postgres Regex Replace with a capture group. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
